# sudo being backgrounded not the command

Tags: macos, macports, bash

I have the following in my ~/.profile file...

`alias mysqlstart='sudo /opt/local/bin/mysqld_safe5 &'`

However, when I type `$ mysqlstart`. I'm not asked for my password and mysql doesn't start.
When I foreground the job, it's stuck on asking for my password.

Is there a way of setting the alias so the `/opt/local/bin/mysqld_safe5` is backgrounded not `sudo`?

This is my shell's version information:

`GNU bash, version 4.2.37(2)-release (i386-apple-darwin11.3.0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`sudo` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo):

> The -b (background) option tells sudo to run the given command in the
>   background.  Note that if you use the -b option you cannot use shell
>   job
>                      control to manipulate the process.  Most interactive commands will fail
>                      to work properly in background mode.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware of the `sudo -b` option, which sounds like the better solution.

I have used something like the following before, which I suppose has the advantage that it allows for job control by the shell:

`alias mysqlstart='sudo true; sudo /opt/local/bin/mysqld_safe5 &'`

The first command `sudo true` should prompt you for your password while not really doing anything, but allows the second `sudo` to execute without prompting for your password.